# what's the difference between prepareQuery and preparecqlStatement in java for cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra

I need some clarification about the Cassandra in java code.

I am trying to execute the select query using two statement

```
Rows<String, String> dateDetail = getKeyspace().prepareQuery(dimDateCF)
                    .setConsistencyLevel(DEFAULT_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL)
                    .searchWithIndex().setRowLimit(1)
                    .addExpression()
                    .whereColumn("date")
                    .equals().value(currentDate).execute().getResult();
```

and

```
OperationResult<CqlStatementResult> dateDetail2 = getKeyspace().prepareCqlStatement().withCql("select * FROM date where date='"+currentDate+"'").execute();
```

both result is to get the columns and rows for particular date,my question is  prepareQuery execute in cassandra-cli and prepareCqlStatement will execute in cqlsh -3 version ?